# Closest point of one SO(3) submanifold onto another submanifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

*I apologize if this is a well known problem and I've just missed the answer, but I have searched fairly extensively. Perhaps there is another way to phrase it that I've been missing?*

*This question was posted four days ago at [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2499941/closest-point-of-one-so3-submanifold-onto-another-submanifold), but with no answer or comments.*

Suppose there are two submanifolds $M_1$ and $M_2$ embedded within $SO(3)$.

$M_1 =\left\{ P_1 e^{\, \mathbf \xi_1 t} | t \in \left[0, ^{2 \pi}/_{|\xi_1|} \right] \right\}$

$M_2 =\left\{ P_2 e^{\, \mathbf \xi_2 t} | t \in \left[0, ^{2 \pi}/_{|\xi_2|} \right] \right\}$

with $P_1, P_2 \in SO(3)$ and $\mathbf \xi_1, \mathbf \xi_2 \in \mathfrak{so(3)}$

Is there an analytic way to determine the pair of points on $M_1$ and $M_2$ that minimizes the geodesic distance between them.

$\arg \min d(m_1, m_2)=  \| \log m_1 m_2^\top\|\; : \; m_1 \in M_1, m_2 \in M_2$

---

The specific problem I'm trying to solve is for a rigid body with an initial attitude and a fixed rotation rate, what is the nearest attitude it will reach with a defined roll and pitch so $\xi_1$ would also point only in the direction of $i_z$ if that further constraint helps. I can solve this numerically, but am looking for an analytic solution to try and implement this on a resource constrained platform.

Comment: Should all those $\subseteq$'s be $\in$'s? Also, could you clarify what quantity is being minimized and what the quantifiers on $m_1$ and $m_2$ are?

Comment: @MTyson thanks, yes they should. i hope my edit makes the question more clear!

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you meant $P_1, P_2 \in SO(3)$, and that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are 1-parameter subgroups. Assuming you want the biinvariant metric on $SO(3)$, the 1-parameter subgroups are also geodesics. If I were doing it, I'd lift them to the double cover (the 3-sphere), where they're great circles, apply an isometry to both of them so that the first moves to standard position, say the $xy$-plane (where $z=w=0$), and find the closest points there. Then undo your isometry.

Comment: and would finding the closest point in the 3-sphere allow an analytic approach to finding the closet points, or would it still be an iterative procedure?

Comment: It would be analytic.